# Setting font to paragraph in pdf using iText java

Tags: java, fonts, itext, paragraph

I was trying to create pdf using iText in java. And am failed when I tried to set font to paragraph. The exact problem is only the font size is not getting applied. I used the following code.

```
StringReader strReader = new StringReader(content);
arrList = HTMLWorker.parseToList(strReader, null);

Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont("c:\\ARIALUN0.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 
    BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 6, Font.BOLD, new Color(0, 0, 0));

Paragraph para = new Paragraph();  
para.setFont(font);
for (int k = 0; k < arrList.size(); ++k) {                   
    para.add((com.lowagie.text.Element)arrList.get(k)); 
}
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 12):

//use this code.Sometimes setfont() willnot work with Paragraph

```
try
{

    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(name);
    Document doc=new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);
    doc.open();

    Font f=new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,50.0f,Font.UNDERLINE,BaseColor.RED);
    Paragraph p=new Paragraph("New PdF",f);

    p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);

    doc.add(p);
    doc.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really strange but it works, when setting the alignment the font must be set in the constructor

Answer (score 3):

I was pretty confused and almost posted the wrong answer to this.

Your paragraph is having its font set correctly. Just try inserting a String to see.

Your problem lies in your for loop. To the paragraph, you're adding a Element objects. An Element is composed of Chunk objects, which each have their own Font data.

Try setting the Font of the Chunks in your Elements when they are instantiated. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I am parsing the data using HTMLWorker and storing in arrayList. Chunks allows only string data. If the arraylist items are converted to string then the html tags are not applying properly in the document.

Comment: In your (Element) arrList.get(k), you're adding an Element, which is composed of Chunks. The Chunks have font data already. Try casting the Chunks, changing the font and the recomposing the element. Because of the cinflict, I don't think there is another way to do this with iText.

Comment: @Nims:
@Zach: I have the same problem , but i didn't understand how am I supposed to cast the Chunks? can u give some kind of an example? thank's.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,It will save the style of the text:

```
 Paragraph _p = new Paragraph();

         _p.setFont(regular);

        ArrayList htmlObjs = (ArrayList) HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(text_), null);

        for (int k = 0; k < htmlObjs.size(); ++k)
        {
            ArrayList<Chunk> chunk = ((Paragraph) htmlObjs.get(k)).getChunks();
            for (int l = 0; l < chunk.size(); l++)
            {
                Font _original_chunk_font = chunk.get(l).getFont();
                Font _newchunk_font = new Font(unicode);

                _newchunk_font.setFamily(_original_chunk_font.getFamilyname());
                _newchunk_font.setStyle(_original_chunk_font.getStyle());
                _newchunk_font.setSize(_original_chunk_font.getSize());
                _newchunk_font.setColor(_original_chunk_font.getColor());

                chunk.get(l).setFont(_newchunk_font);
            }
            _p.add((Element)htmlObjs.get(k));
        }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for saving my day!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new in this.
>      but i'm showing u a simplest way to set font to
>   paragraph.

```
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph(" Hello World ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
document.close();
```

> By this way i'm changing the font, font size , color etc.
>
> this worked for me..
>
> Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

For adding `Font` to *itextpdf* `Paragraph` you can simply use a `Chunk` then you can set `Font` to `Chunk` add that `Chunk` to `Paragraph` afterwards.

**Example:**

```
Font f3 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
Chunk c3 = new Chunk("INVOICE", f3);
c3.setBackground(BaseColor.WHITE);       
Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph(c3);
p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```